# Split a very complicated string of characters with R

Tags: r, split

I have 50000 lines of conversations between two people and a typical line of that
conversation
`2014/07/06, 10:40:42 PM: Franckess ©: I'll leave my student card with him`
I would like to split each line so that I get a data frame with the following variables: **Date**; **Time**; **Person** & **Message**.
I am hoping to be able to do it using R (no Excel), then I would carry on with sentiment analysis.

Could anyone assist me with this?

Comment: What is the source of the data? Can you share more than one line? Do they all have the same general pattern?

Comment: you can use ```strsplit``` with ```" "``` the first contains the date (remove the ```,```) the 2nd contains the time the 3th contains pm: the forth the name the fifth ©: the rest the conversation

Comment: The source of my data is Whatsapp conversation. The lines all have similar pattern. Here is another one: `2014/07/06, 10:38:34 PM: Viv M.: I can just fetch it from him`

Comment: @phonixor I am not sure to follow you! I have tried to read the help file for `strsplit` but could not figure it out yet :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
> string <- 
     "2014/07/06, 10:40:42 PM: Franckess ©: I'll leave my student card with him"
> s <- strsplit(string, "(, )|(: )|( [[:print:]]: )")[[1]]
> names(s) <- c("Date", "Time", "Person", "Message")
> data.frame(as.list(s))
#         Date        Time    Person                             Message
# 1 2014/07/06 10:40:42 PM Franckess I'll leave my student card with him
```

In the `strsplit` regular expression `"(, )|(: )|( \\xA9: )"`, we have

- `(, )`  look for a comma then a space
- `|`     or
- `(: )`  a semicolon then a space
- `|`     or
- `( \\xA9: )`  a space, then a copyright symbol, then a colon and another space

To produce a data frame from multiple strings, you will need to bring them all together with a function like `do.call` with `rbind`.

```
> dc <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(string, "(, )|(: )|( \\xA9: )"))
> colnames(dc) <- c("Date", "Time", "Person", "Message")
> as.data.frame(dc)
#         Date        Time    Person                             Message
# 1 2014/07/06 10:40:42 PM Franckess I'll leave my student card with him
```

Comment: I would suggest removing the `[[1]]` and showing a `do.call(rbind, ...)` for the result of `strsplit`. It's doubtful that they just want to split this single string.

Comment: But +1 :-) Was about to post something quite similar.

Comment: Brilliant @AnandaMahto :D

Comment: Updated to include that, and a modified regular expression that may be useful.

Comment: it is a c for copyright, but it's not really needed!

Comment: Ahh, good because `\xA9` actually does search for the copyright symbol.

Comment: @RichardScriven: in the assignment to dc, could you explain how do.call(rbind ... differs in results from simply rbind?  I added a second string and found that rbind alone simply added four more columns, whereas do.call(rbind ... put them one under another on the console.  Would you mind adding an explanation for newbies as to what does do.call do?  ?do.call isn't too useful: "constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it."  So, it calls rbind with rbind's arguments?

Comment: That's a bit off topic for this question.  Before I explain it, have you gone through `example(do.call)` and `example(rbind)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
  library(stringr)
  str1 <- c("2014/07/06, 10:40:42 PM: Franckess ©: I'll leave my student card with him", "2014/07/06, 10:38:34 PM: Viv M.: I can just fetch it from him")

  str2 <- str_replace_all(str1, perl(':(?= )'),",")
```

#### Explanation

`:(?= ), ",")` replaces `:` followed by a `space` with `,`

```
   setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, str_split(str2, ", ")), stringsAsFactors=F), c("Date", "Time", "Person", "Message")) # split based on `, `
  #       Date        Time      Person                             Message
 #1 2014/07/06 10:40:42 PM Franckess © I'll leave my student card with him
 #2 2014/07/06 10:38:34 PM      Viv M.        I can just fetch it from him
```

#### Update

You can also use:

```
  read.csv(text=str2, sep=",",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
 #          V1           V2           V3                                   V4
 #1 2014/07/06  10:40:42 PM  Franckess ©  I'll leave my student card with him
 #2 2014/07/06  10:38:34 PM       Viv M.         I can just fetch it from him
```

Comment: @Franckess, I just updated the code with a compact code.

Comment: Thanks @akrun for going the extra-mile for me. I doing the sentiment analysis on the texts and it looks good :D

Answer (score 0):

When i'm parsing structured strings, I like to use regular expressions to capture parts of matches, and then extract those matches with a [regcapturedmatch.R](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) helper function. For example

```
msg<-c("2014/07/06, 10:40:42 PM: Franckess ©: I'll leave my student card with him", "2014/07/06, 10:38:34 PM: Viv M.: I can just fetch it from him")

m<-regexpr("([\\d/]+), ([\\d: AMP]+): (.*): (.*)$",msg, perl=T)

dd<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, regcapturedmatches(msg, m)))

names(dd)<-c("Date","Time","Person","Message")
```